# How to get subset of dataset after K-means clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset `val_lab` as follows:

```
[[ 52.85560436 -23.61958699  34.40273147]
 [ 70.44462451  -2.74272277  80.32988099]
 [ 38.32222473 -11.22753928  24.09593474]
 [ 84.83470029  -7.73898094  28.03636332]
 [ 76.48246093   0.13784934  76.23718213]
 [ 61.21154496   2.24080039   9.38927616]
 [ 39.88027333  37.32959609 -19.0592156 ]...]
```

I use K-means clustering from sklearn and got the prediction value:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
y_pred = KMeans(n_clusters= 5 , random_state=0 ).fit_predict(val_lab)
>>>[3 0 1 3 0 3 4 1 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 0 3 1 0 3...]
```

now I want to get the value in every cluster, for example, if `y_pred = 3`
I get:

```
[[ 52.85560436 -23.61958699  34.40273147] 
 [ 84.83470029  -7.73898094  28.03636332]
  ... ]
```

(0 and 3 row)

Right now, my idea is:

```
val_lab_3 = []
for i in range(y_pred.shape[0]):
       if y_pred[i] == 3:
              val_lab_3.append(val_lab[i,:])
```

Is there some better idea, because I want to get the subsets in all the clusters. It this too complicated, especially assuming more clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I'm understanding this correctly, your rows above are being classified as 0,1,2,3,4 (5 clusters from what I see) and you want to get all of them together.

Pandas would be a good utility. You can use this cluster prediction and make it a new column, then just select those rows where your cluster label is 3

e.g. (assuming your call your new column `preds` and your original numpy array is called `val_lab`):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(val_lab)
df['preds'] = y_pred
threes = df[df['preds'] == 3]  # This is what you want
print(threes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `val_lab` is a `numpy` array. In that case,

```
val_lab[y_pred == 3, :]
```

Will work.